# ipython pandas plot does not show

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython, anaconda

I am using the anaconda distribution of ipython/Qt console. I want to plot things inline so I type the following from the ipython console:

```
%pylab inline
```

Next I type the tutorial at (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html) into ipython...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
ts = pd.Series(randn(1000), index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

... and this is all that i get back:

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x109253410>
```

But there is no plot. What could be wrong? Is there another command that I need to supply? The tutorial suggests that that is all that I need to type.

Comment: When you typed in `%pylab inline`, did it gives you back any error? Or some kind of message? And how did you started the `qtconsole`? Also did you updated yourself to the new version of pandas and ipython, since anaconda comes with the 0.11 version of pandas, and 0.13.2 version of IPython

Comment: those versions are correct. they need to be higher versions?

Comment: i tried installing a better version of pandas through `call("pip install --upgrade pandas", shell=True)` but it returned `0`

Comment: No, don't use pip with anaconda :D Use conda: `conda update pandas` and `conda update ipython`. But you haven't answered me the more important question about the error message and how did you started the qtconsole.

Comment: FYI returning 0 indicates success.

Comment: I simply started Qt console / ipython from the anaconda launcher that comes with the distro for mac OS X.

Comment: @cantdutchthis Open a terminal window and start it from with `ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline` and try that again just the plotting code without the `%pylab` command. It's possible that the launcher is not configured as it should be.

Comment: @cantdutchthis try to add at the end `plt.show()`

Comment: turns out it started working when i turned the computer on and off ... must've been something weird in the settings it seems

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Plots are not displayed until you run

> plt.show()

Answer (score 9):

There could be 2 ways to approach this problem:

1) Either invoke the inline/osx/qt/gtk/gtk3/tk backend. Depends on the ipython console that you have been using. So, simply do:

**`%matplotlib inline`** #***Here the inline backend is invoked, which removes the necessity of calling show after each plot.***

or for ipython/qt console, do:

**`%matplotlib qt`** #***This one works for me, thus, depends on the ipython console you use.***

#

2) **Or, do the traditional way as aforementioned** (***already answered above on this page***):

`plt.show()` *#However, you will have to call this show function each time.*